# Migrar una aplicación ASP MVC 2 a ASP MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

Tengo un problema a la hora de actualizar un proyecto desde asp mvc 2 a asp mvc 5, originalmente el proyecto estaba en asp mvc 1 y logre migrarlo a asp mvc 2, lo hice instalando vs studio 2008 en windows xp y desde ahí cambié la version de .net a la que apuntaba el proyecto.

Sin embargo quiero migrarlo a vs 2015 community y asp mvc 5, pero al querer abrir el proyecto, obtengo el mensaje de que el tipo de proyecto no existe.

Mi pregunta es: **¿Existe alguna forma de hacer compatible un proyecto de vs 2008 mvc 2, con vs 2015 community?**

Comment: No crees que seria mas fácil migrar a MVC 4 y de ahí lo pasas a MVC 5

Comment: @JuanGlezz como puedo hacerlo?? estoy buscando la forma de hacerlo, el problema es que el proyecto no se abre en vs 2015.

Comment: Tengo entendido que VS2015 solo soporta MVC 5 y 6, y para hacer la migración te sugeriría que revises [este enlace](https://magedfarag.wordpress.com/2012/10/14/migrate-mvc2-to-mvc4/), nunca lo he hecho pero tal ves funcione

Comment: @JuanGlezz gracias lo voy a revisar.

Comment: Me late que el truco está en revisar el archivo .sln del proyecto que tienes con algún otra solución que haya sido creado en la nueva versión. Cambiar unos guids, actualizar números de versión y quizás la magia se presente :)

Comment: por curiosidad hermano, ¿lograste solucionar este caso?

Comment: @fredyfx no, a la final lo que hice es implementar el proyecto desde un proyecto mvc 5 limpio, no pude migrar directamente avanzando version por version.

Comment: vale, entonces cerramos la pregunta o acepta la respuesta ofrecida que contiene el escenario que acabas de mencionar :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer es una jugada forzada para como van las cosas.
El problema de Visual Studio es que a partir de la versión 2012 no es muy amigable con la retro compatibilidad  con otros proyectos de ASP.Net antiguos, es por eso el mensaje que te aparece.

Ahora bien Aunque encuentres una forma de pasar de MVC2 a MVC5 de un salto creeme al final tu proyecto va a dar mucho problemas.

Una de mis recomendaciones sería migrar primero a MVC3 luego pasar a MVC4 y por ultimo migrar al 5.  En caso de insistir en tu jugada te aconsejo usar el VS Community 2012, es mejor para esa maniobra.

Logre hacerlo varias veces pero al final siempre opto por hacer el proyecto MVC5 limpio. Creeme es mi mejor recomendación; Comenzar con un nuevo proyecto MVC5 e ir integrando cada parte paso a paso. Se que es mas trabajo pero es mejor y mas pulcro para tu aplicación.